# Issue in connecting to cordatestnet via node explorer

Tags: corda

I am using corda opensource 3.2 in azure marketplace by following the link : https://docs.corda.net/head/testnet-explorer-corda.html. and I am able to connect to the corda testnet via node explorer and do transactions(using corda-finance jar as in documentation). But I tried copying cordapp-example jar to the /opt/corda/cordapps/ folder in the azure machine and unable to connect to the corda testnet (error is something related to the finance cordapp). So , is it not possible to connect to the corda testnet by using our customized cordapp or  Am I missing any steps that need to be followed?

I got the following error:

> net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException:
>   net.corda.finance.flows.CashConfigDataFlow at
>   net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:238)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.startFlowDynamic(Unknown Source) at
>   net.corda.explorer.model.IssuerModel$cashAppConfiguration$1.invoke(IssuerModel.kt:27)
>   at
>   net.corda.explorer.model.IssuerModel$cashAppConfiguration$1.invoke(IssuerModel.kt:13)
>   at
>   net.corda.client.jfx.utils.ObservableUtilities$sam$Function$24de0b22.apply(ObservableUtilities.kt)
>   at org.fxmisc.easybind.EasyBind$2.computeValue(EasyBind.java:70) at
>   javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.get(ObjectBinding.java:153) at
>   javafx.beans.binding.ObjectExpression.getValue(ObjectExpression.java:50)
>   at org.fxmisc.easybind.EasyBind$2.computeValue(EasyBind.java:70) at
>   javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.get(ObjectBinding.java:153) at
>   javafx.beans.binding.ObjectExpression.getValue(ObjectExpression.java:50)
>   at net.corda.client.jfx.utils.ChosenList.rechoose(ChosenList.kt:45) at
>   net.corda.client.jfx.utils.ChosenList.access$rechoose(ChosenList.kt:23)
>   at
>   net.corda.client.jfx.utils.ChosenList$1.invalidated(ChosenList.kt:34)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>   at
>   javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.invalidate(ObjectBinding.java:172)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.BindingHelperObserver.invalidated(BindingHelperObserver.java:51)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>   at
>   javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.invalidate(ObjectBinding.java:172)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.BindingHelperObserver.invalidated(BindingHelperObserver.java:51)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>   at
>   javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
>   at
>   javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
>   at
>   javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
>   at
>   net.corda.client.jfx.model.NodeMonitorModel.register(NodeMonitorModel.kt:113)
>   at net.corda.explorer.views.LoginView.login(LoginView.kt:31) at
>   net.corda.explorer.views.LoginView$login$$inlined$apply$lambda$1.call(LoginView.kt:42)
>   at
>   net.corda.explorer.views.LoginView$login$$inlined$apply$lambda$1.call(LoginView.kt:13)
>   at
>   javafx.scene.control.Dialog.impl_setResultAndClose(Dialog.java:1026)
>   at
>   javafx.scene.control.DialogPane.lambda$createButton$599(DialogPane.java:777)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74) at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49) at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198) at
>   javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413) at
>   javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185) at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74) at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54) at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198) at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757) at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485) at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762) at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494) at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555) at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937) at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native
>   Method) at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:218)
>   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107) at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:583)
>   at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474) at
>   javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.showAndWait(HeavyweightDialog.java:162)
>   at javafx.scene.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:341) at
>   net.corda.explorer.views.LoginView.login(LoginView.kt:71) at
>   net.corda.explorer.Main.start(Main.kt:66) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.runLoop(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   net.corda.finance.flows.CashConfigDataFlow

Comment: Hi Neenu, can you update your question with the error you received please? Then I'll be able to identify your issue.

Comment: Are you keeping the `corda-finance` CorDapp in the `/opt/corda/cordapps/` folder when you add the `cordapp-example` CorDapp?

Comment: I stopped the corda service and deleted the corda-finance jar, After that I added the cordapp-example jar and restarted the corda service.                                              
Nov 23 05:06:52 cordaep3j java[10452]: Loaded CorDapps                         : cordapp-example-0.1, corda-core-3.2-corda-RC02 Nov 23 05:06:52 cordaep3j java[10452]: Node for "C8f598055-24bb-4011-9313-5895800b55f2" started up and registered in 42.93 sec

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because you no longer have the `corda-finance` CorDapp installed on your node.

Simply keep the `corda-finance` CorDapp in your node's `cordapps` folder when adding the `cordapp-example` CorDapp. A node can run multiple CorDapps at once.

Comment: Just now I tried the same, I am able to connect to testnet but the functions like pay etc are related to the cordapp-finance. My doubt is that if we add any other jar file with the cordapp-finance jar in the cordapps folder and connect to testnet, why are we not able to see the other cordapp functionality (in this case cordapp-example)?

Comment: You should see the flows from both. But if you are using the Node Explorer, that is only set up to run the `cordapp-finance` flows. You'd need to create your own UI/RPC client to interact with the node and run your other flows.